# Unable to book performance in May at Paris Opera?

Tags: france, bookings, paris

I registered for an account on the website of Paris Opera and tried to book Tosca for May 10 https://www.operadeparis.fr/en/season-20-21/opera/tosca . However, after I clicked on “Book”, the webpage showed "Sorry, the requested page does not exist or you are not eligible to this offer.” Does it mean the performance will not take place (perhaps due to COVID-related restrictions)? Or maybe I can only book the performance some time later? (I set a reminder for myself to book it now; the last time I looked, the website said that the performance will be available for booking starting from 9 Feb.)

Comment: Performances (I'm not sure if all or just many) in February have certainly [been cancelled](https://www.operadeparis.fr/en/info/cancellation-performances-february). There doesn't appear to be any information about cancellations of performances scheduled after February, although at this point I'd say it seems a reasonable assumption. The message about the page not existing sounds like an IT error regardless of whether the shows are happening or not. I imagine you're better off asking the venue directly.

Comment: I kind of hate to say it, but how is this travel-related? i.e. a person who lives in Paris would (presumably) face the same issue.

Comment: @ChrisH Yep, though curiously enough they don't even seem to have any contact method in addition to a phone number... https://www.operadeparis.fr/en/contacts Sent an email to an address listed on their FB account though I'm not sure if I'll get a response.

Comment: @CGCampbell I guess if viewed in this light then any question regarding a tourist attraction can be said to be somewhat invalid since of course people living in that city should be the first in line to visit the said attraction... Though maybe this is how this SE defines the scope of the questions. Not sure. Would you suggest another SE which would be the right place to post this?

Comment: Local people will likely get a sense of what is going on from the local or national news, while foreign (or cross country) tourists are more restricted in getting accidental news and questions like this are acceptable.

Comment: I wouldn’t count on the theaters to reopen before 2022 at this point, given the trajectory of cases and vaccinations.

Answer (score 9):

OK, I did get an answer from the email address listed on their Facebook page resa.internet@operadeparis.fr, even though this address was not listed on their homepage:

> Dear Sir/Madam,
>
> You would like to book tickets for the performance of Tosca on May, 10th 2021.
>
> We inform you that in application of government directives, reservations are currently suspended.
>
> All the information concerning the shows scheduled from February to July 2021 will soon be detailed on our website operadeparis.fr and our mobile application.
>
> We thank you for your understanding.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Anaïs – Chargée des relations avec le public
>
> Direction de l’Expérience Spectateur & Marketing
>
> Opéra national de Paris
>
> Opéra Bastille - 120 rue de Lyon - 75012 Paris

Comment: "Direction de l’Expérience Spectateur & Marketing" - Franglais is a wonderful language!